# Update table field 1 to field 2 where field 1 equals field 3

Tags: mysql, sql

So I need something like this:

```
UPDATE j3gll_komento_comments 
SET parent_id = (
    SELECT j3gll_komento_comments.new_id
) WHERE parent_id in (
    SELECT j3gll_komento_comments.id 
    FROM j3gll_komento_comments
);
```

Basically the primary key is new_id but the parent_id is still tied to id.  So I need to update the tables so that the parent_id shows the new_id instead of the (old) id column.

I tried what I just posted but got zero results.

So this is on a commenting system obviously. So I had to change the primary key from id to new_id and they do not share the same values. But parent_id still references the id column. So post B might be a child under post A but it wouldn't know that because it's parent_id now references an old irrelevant number. I need to convert the parent_ids to match the new_ids.

Comment: Can you provide an example ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
UPDATE j3gll_komento_comments SET parent_id = new_id WHERE parent_id = id;
```

---

**EDIT:** New activity on this question 8 years later made me look at it again. In case anyone else comes across this, I think this is what OP probably needed:

```
UPDATE
  j3gll_komento_comments AS child
  INNER JOIN j3gll_komento_comments AS parent
    ON child.parent_id = parent.id
SET
  child.parent_id = parent.new_id
WHERE
  child.parent_id != parent.new_id;
```

The WHERE clause is optional since all of the records need to be updated in this instance, but some SQL clients prevent you from doing an UPDATE without a WHERE clause to stop you from accidentally updating all records if you forgot your WHERE clause.

Comment: I don't really know what I mean...but it's not that since zero replacements happened.
So this is on a commenting system obviously. So I had to change the primary key from id to new_id and they do not share the same values.  But parent_id still references the id column.

So post B might be a child under post A but it wouldn't know that because it's parent_id now references an old irrelevant number.  I need to convert the parent_ids to match the new_ids.